# Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. Rules included

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I know that this is an issue that is occurring with the firebase rules for the project but I don't know why it's happening. I'm trying to get a snapshot of the documents that are currently inside the path but I am getting the firebase permission error

Here is the code, note this is using nuxt vue, I'm just getting started with the framework so this might be odd but as far as I understand this should work:

```
mounted(){
      this.getPosts();
    },
    methods:{

      getPosts(){
        database.collection('blog').doc('yP6aYXvisFbTsqtQ3MEfuyz6xYE3').collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
          console.log(snapshot)
        })
      }
    }
```

And these are the rules:

```
match /blog {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == 'BoTJcdHh9ogYZUWEaKWbEkuPzTJ2'
    }
```

My understanding is that anything in this path should be able to be read but the permission error is still showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the rule at the document level, not the collection.

So for example:

```
match /blog/{blogId}/posts/{postId}  {
        allow read;
    }
```

From the documentation:

> All match statements should point to documents, not collections. A
> match statement can point to a specific document, as in match
> /cities/SF or use wildcards to point to any document in the specified
> path, as in match /cities/{city}.

Read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure